# Jquery - how to remove content dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a table with Rows. And i have a soccer field  div with 
Child DIVs for each player!

When i Click on a Row, i have a JQuery Funktion who adds The player into My Field (with a playerID)! After That the picked player is greyed out!

But now  i want to remove the player from the Field (dynamically Based on His ID) when i am clicking again on the grey row!

How could i so do something like this without selecting by a Static selector like

```
$("#goalkeeper").empty();
```

Here is My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcvcga8k/30/

Thx for alllll hints ;)

Alex

EDIT: Here is onyl the relevant Code:

**Javascript:** (the main releveant part is here the is my addGoalkeeperByClickEvent() Function and that I am using "#goalie" as selector, thats why this solution works at the moment, but i want to use always the player who the user clicked) dynamically... but i am talking here only about a solution to remove the player, adding a player is successfully working already...

```
var GoalKeeperQuantity = 0;
  var DefenderQuantity = 0;
  var MidfielderQuantity = 0;
  var ForwardQuantity = 0;
  var totalPlayersOnField = 0;


  function addGoalkeeperByClickEvent(playerName) {
    $(document).off('click', '.goalKepperRow, .goalKepperRowGrey, .greyRow').on('click', '.goalKepperRow, .goalKepperRowGrey, .greyRow', function() {


      $('#goalkeeperLine div p').first().parent().html("<img src='https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/shirt/1188/shirt-333.svg'><span class='ui-icon  ui-icon-circle-close remove' style='top: -69.0833px; left: 34.3167px;'></span>".concat(playerName));

            if ($(this).css("background-color")==="rgb(217, 217, 217)") {
                    $(this).attr('class', 'greyRow');
          GoalKeeperQuantity++;
            totalPlayersOnField++;
          //alert(GoalKeeperQuantity);
            }else{
                    $(this).attr('class', 'goalKepperRow');
          GoalKeeperQuantity--;
            totalPlayersOnField--;
          //alert(GoalKeeperQuantity);


         $("#goalie").empty()
         $("#goalie").html("<p></p>")


            }


    });
  };




// If the user clicks on the "x", remove the player and subtract the qnt of players
$("#field").on("click", "span.remove", function(e) {
  // remove player from field (means >>> empty the relevant DIV)
  var me = $(this).parent();
  me.empty();

  // add p elemnt to the empty div
  me.html("<p></p>")
  var title = '';

  // Check what kind of position the user has removed
  switch ($(this).parent().attr('position')) {
    case "goalkeeper":
      GoalKeeperQuantity--;
      alert(GoalKeeperQuantity);
      break;
    case "defender":
      DefenderQuantity--;
      alert(DefenderQuantity);
      break;
    case "midfielder":
      MidfielderQuantity--;
      alert(MidfielderQuantity);
      break;
    case "forward":
      ForwardQuantity--;
      alert(ForwardQuantity);
      break;
  }
});
```

**HTML** Here i've got a simple table on the right side and in the middle a football field (where i can add and remove a football player)

```
<div id="container">


  <!-- Main Content area -->
  <section id="content">
    <div id="field">

      <span id="goalkeeperLine">   
          <div id="goalie" position="goalkeeper" class="drop thirdColumn rear">
            <p></p>
          </div>
     </span>
     </div>
  </section>

  <!-- SIDBAR RIGHT / TABLE OF PLAYERS -->
  <aside>
    <table class="player_table">
      <tr style="background-color: #fad32b; color:black; font-size:14px;">
        <td style="width:32%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Playername</td>
        <td style="width:13%">Club</td>
        <td style="width:9%">Pos.</td>
        <td style="width:15%">Points</td>
        <td style="width:20%">Costs (in Mio.)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="gk1" player-type="goalkeeper" class="goalKepperRow" onclick="addGoalkeeperByClickEvent('Manuel Neuer');">
        <td >
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Manuel Neuer
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>GK</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>12.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr  id="df1" player-type="defender" class="defenderRow" onclick="addDefenderByClickEvent('Jerome Boateng');">
        <td>
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Jerome Boateng
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>DF</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>11.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="df2" player-type="defender" class="defenderRow" onclick="addDefenderByClickEvent('Holger Badstuber');">
        <td>
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Holger Badstuber
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>DF</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>9.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="df2" player-type="defender" class="defenderRow" onclick="addDefenderByClickEvent('Mats Hummels');">
        <td>
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Mats Hummels
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>DF</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>10.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="mf1" player-type="midfielder" class="midfielderRow" onclick="addMidfielderByClickEvent('Semih Kedhira');">
        <td>
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Semih Kedhira
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>DF</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>8.9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="mf1" player-type="forward" class="forwardRow" onclick="addForwardByClickEvent('Thomas Müller');">
        <td>
            <span id="#btnAddPlayer" class="btnAddPlayer">+</span>Thomas Müller
        </td>
        <td><img width="12%" src="https://d34h6ikdffho99.cloudfront.net/uploads/real_team/emblem/1098/logo-296.svg">FCB</td>
        <td>DF</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>6.3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </aside>
```

**CSS** (i know its a long version, but many things are important)

```
/* Content
--------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  width: 40%;
}


/* field
--------------------------------------------- */

#field {
  background-image: url(https://picload.org/image/rdllrgdp/field2.png);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0%;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Sidebar
--------------------------------------------- */

#sidebar {
  float: left;
  padding: 0% 1% 1%;
  margin: 1% 0% 0% 0%;
  width: 15%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.goalkeeper,
.defender,
.forward,
.midfielder {
  float: left;
  padding: 0% 1% 0%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  width: 39%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.drop {
  border: 1px;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 5vw;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 17%;
  border-style: dashed;
}

.ui-droppable-active {
  color: #cfcfcf;
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.ui-droppable-hover {
  border: 2px dotted #fefe88;
}

.rear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.firstColumn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 98px;
}

.secondColumn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 176px;
}

.def {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}

.mid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 183px;
}

.for {
  position: absolute;
  top: 277px;
}

.thirdColumn {
  left: 251px;
}

.fourthColumn {
  left: 327px;
}

.fifthColumn {
  left: 403px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
}

#field span.remove:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.btnAddPlayer {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #4ad934;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4ad934, #37ab26);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btnAddPlayer:hover {
  background: #26ff00;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26ff00, #1ee000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26ff00, #1ee000);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26ff00, #1ee000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26ff00, #1ee000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26ff00, #1ee000);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.forwardRowGrey:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.midfielderRowGrey:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.defenderRowGrey:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.goalKepperRowGrey:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.forwardRow:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.midfielderRow:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.defenderRow:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.goalKepperRow:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.defender:hover span.btnAddPlayer,
.goalkeeper:hover span.btnAddPlayer {
  visibility: visible;
}

.goalKepperRow, .defenderRow, .midfielderRow, .forwardRow {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.greyRow{
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;   
}

.goalKepperRowGrey, .defenderRowGrey, .midfielderRowGrey, .forwardRowGrey{
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.goalKepperRow:hover, .defenderRow:hover, .midfielderRow:hover, .forwardRow:hover, .goalKepperRowGrey:hover, .defenderRowGrey:hover, .midfielderRowGrey:hover, .forwardRowGrey:hover
{
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code in your question itself! Not in an external fiddle! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, that greyed out seems to work only for the first row...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ok i will post a new answer just with the relevant code... takes a while :)

Comment: @Dodorido: yes becasue i only tested it with the first Row

Comment: @nbg15, no, don't do that. Edit that code into your *question* instead.

Comment: @nbg15, So goalkeeper seems to work both ways (he get greyed on click, gets removed on click on grey row). It's the other players that you want to fix?

Comment: @Dodorido: its only working, becasue i have a STATIC selector in my addGoalkeeperByClickEvent() <--- btw: this function also removes players and adds players... and at the end of this function I have a #goalie selector becasue my field where my goalkeeper was placed has the name "#goalie". Thats why it looks like it works, BUT i need a solution where i can click on each player and the player could be remove only by clicking on the playerRow (becasue removing by clicking the "X" is already working fine :)

THX for your help ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ok I added now all important thing to my first post ;) THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Fiddle example has a span with id of "goalkeeperLine" containing a div with an id of "goalie".

[image]

You can use these jQuery functions to hide and show the "goalie" div.

- $("#goalie).hide;
- $("#goalie").show;

Howerver, you may need to move the "goalkeeperLine" span tag inside the the "goalie" div so as to make that element be hidden when the div is hidden.

Comment: thx for your fast answer, but how can i do this dynamically based on the (player)Row i have clicked? I thought maybe i have to work with an ID of the player...

Comment: and btw, i have to empty the div completley and add only and empty <p> Element, when i use your suggestions, i only hide and show it BUT not clear / empty my DIV. but thx :)

Comment: You may need to consider HTML changes to get the desired behavior you are looking for. Also consider using the Chrome browser's "Inspect" function (which I had used to produce the displayed image in my answer), which can enable you to change CSS attributes interactively. This may be helpful as you explore your options.

Comment: You can try to keep it as is and add the jQuery to remove the "goalie" div after the appropriate user event occurs. But you may continue to see the enclosing "goalkeeperLine" span tag border line, etc., after hiding the inner div (perhaps that's OK for your purposes). You may also be able to hide the span and the enclosed div and that may work fine. But my preference would be to use a div that encapsulates everything used for toggling between show and hide. This could be done by adding another div or changing the existing div to enclose the span tags instead of span tags enclosing the div.

Comment: Hey John, its working (to 95%) correctly now :) if you click on the 2nd, 3rd and fourth Row and click again on the grey rows, the player will be deleted from the field, but when i try to add some defenders and right after that one goalkeeper, and after that try to remove these players.. everything crashes :) I am trying to find the bug, but mayber you also see something like a missing comma or semicolon or some else :(

thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, but my examination of your code was cursory.I suggest that you add alert statements to isolate the cause of your crashes. But for your original question, I'm glad that my answer has helped you to make some progress. You may need to post another question about the new crash issue.

Comment: ahh sorry, its my 3rd Stackoverflow Post ;) didnt know that these up arrows are so important hehe :p have a good one...